# What is the (historical) significance of the name Kazamatsuri?

Tags: japanese-language, sengoku-youko

In the manga *Sengoku Youko* (same author of *Hoshi no Samidare*) a character is asked by Hisahide Matsunaga if he's considered changing his last name to Kazamatsuri, and there's a couple historical easter eggs lurking about. I don't know if there's any (additional) significance to this last name.

[image: manga page]

Because Hisahide in the manga is rather whimsical and has some perception of the flow of time, I feel there's something more lurking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no historical significance in the names.

The names such as [Enra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybrUZ.png), [Kazamatsuri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCT7J.png), and [Arabuki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izp2a.png) are references to his older work, in this case *Sanjin Sadou* and his "Monster Town" oneshot series (see his *Mizukami Satoshi Tanpenshuu* compilation). Some mechanics are reused, such as the Fairy Eye. In the latter oneshot series, there are the [Raidou](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhJsu.jpg) and [Kazamatsuri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ1rU.jpg) clans, who have passed down their magic swords and stuff to modern times with the two families taking care of the town's various demons and their hijinx.

All this probably implies that Sengoku Youko is in the same continuity with *Sanjin Sadou* and the oneshot series.